# How to detect changes from one of many ngModel changes

Tags: angular, angular8

I am starting on Angular and facing a problem that:

For .ts file, I have an object like this:

```
{
  person: {
    a1: {
      name: x
      age: 19
    },
    b1: {
      name: y
      age: 19
    },
    c1: {
      name: z
      age: 19
    }
   ....
}

detechChange() { //any changes come here }
```

Imagine that I have many property in object person

And in HTML part, I have some input that bind data from object person

```
// this one can not iterate
<input [(ngModel)]="person.a1.name"></input>
<input [(ngModel)]="person.a1.age"></input>
<input [(ngModel)]="person.b1.name"></input>
<input [(ngModel)]="person.b1.age"></input>
<input [(ngModel)]="person.c1.name"></input>
<input [(ngModel)]="person.c1.name"></input>
```

Is there any way to detect the changes while one of those input is changed? I know about the event (ngModelChange) but with that I have to bind it to each input, is there anyway that may be smarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way you can do this is using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) because you are managing a lot of inputs and using `ngModel` to accomodate them is not very scalable. With reactive forms you can define the shape of your form and bind it with a `FormGroup` which will be updated automatically when the user changes the form or when you change the form programatically the screen will be updated automatically.

For example you need:

Create a `FormGroup` using a ´FormBuilder`

```
form;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  form = this.fb.group({
     name: ['', [Validators.Required]],
     age: ['', [Validators.Required]]
  })
}
```

In the html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input formControlName="name"></input>
   <input formControlName="age"></input>
</form>
```

To get the value of it:

```
this.form.value;
```

To listen for changes:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => console.log("Value Updated ", value));
```

Of course you can choose another answer here with exactly what you asked which may solve your problem, but it won't look much *clean*.

Comment: where is a method that fires on data change?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8rtcuk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.a1.name" (ngModelChange)="detectChange('a1', 'name', $event)"/>
```

.ts

```
 detectChange(parentKey:string,childKey:string, value:string) {
   console.log(`${parentKey} -> ${childKey}  is ${value}` )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but as I said in the question, I aware of the way to bind (ngModelChange) to each Input, but I don't really like that, I want something that, let's say, do one to all input

Answer (score 2):

Use Reactive Forms, and you can subscribe for the valueChange method of the form to listen for updated values in the form

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    let formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      persons: formBuilder.array([formBuilder.group({
        age: 12,
        name: "Test"
      }), formBuilder.group({
        age: 12,
        name: "Test 123"
      })])
    });

    this.form.valueChanges
      .map((value) => {
        console.log(value);    //Log form changes
        return value;
      })
      .subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
      });
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="persons" *ngFor="let item of form.get('persons').controls;let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
</div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a generic method which detect changes occured in your formFields, you can go with **valueChanges** Observable. For this, you need a Reactive form.

```
this.personForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  person1Name: ['', [ Validators.required ]],
  person1Age: ['', [ Validators.required ]]
}); 

this.personForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
  updatedObject => {
    console.log(updatedObject);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of answers with reactive form, and I would also suggest to use that :) But here's a solution with `ngModel`. You can use the `keyvalue` pipe provided by angular to avoid writing all those inputs longhand. That is, if your object is built like you provide. So you can do the following:

```ts
values = {
  person: {
    a1: {
      name: "x",
      age: 19
    },
    b1: {
      name: "y",
      age: 19
    },
    c1: {
      name: "z",
      age: 19
    }
  }
};

detectChange(key, prop) {
  console.log(`object key: ${key} and property: ${prop}`)
}
```

and then the HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let val of values?.person | keyvalue">
  <input [(ngModel)]="val.value.name" (ngModelChange)="detectChange(val.key, 'name')"/>
  <input [(ngModel)]="val.value.age"  (ngModelChange)="detectChange(val.key, 'age')"/>
</div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6yjzq)**

Comment: Sorry for my less explanation, but my template can not use *ngFor because the design of each part for a1, b1, ... is different, I only put the example so that looks easy, but actually it is more complicated, assumed that It can not interate.

Comment: Also seems that reactive Form will fit this situation, I will try it, thank you for suggestion